# Java BorderLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

Border Layout is not working for me... I have been using a tutorial and copied what they did yet when i run it on my code it does not work. If you could please point out my error and explain why it is an error that would be great thanks! :)
My code is as follows:

```
public static JButton bb = new JButton("Continue");
public TextArea ta = new TextArea(30,140);
TextArea tb = new TextArea(3,140);
public int counter = 0;

//main class
public static void main(String[]args){      
    Frame f = new Frame("---Quest---");
    base ex = new base();
    ex.init();
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.add("Center", ex);
    f.pack();
    f.show(true);
    f.setSize(1100,800);
}
public void init() {        
    bb.addActionListener(this);
    Panel p;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p = new Panel();

    p.add(ta,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p.add(bb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    tb.setLocation(0,50);
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
    ta.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    ta.setEditable(false); 
    add("Center", p);
}
```

Comment: Please 1) fully define what you mean by "does not work". What are you expecting to see? What are you in fact seeing? 2) Please try to format your code so that it conforms to standards and is more easily understood by us. Indentation of code blocks is not something that you should be doing haphazardly, but rather should be 4 spaces for each block and should not vary.

Comment: Also this; `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` is an annotation that should never be used.

Comment: `f.add("Center", ex);` might be better to use `f.add(ex, BorderLayout.CENTER)`.  I might also be a better idea not to use an API which was superseded over 15 years ago...just saying...

Comment: Code formatted for you. Also, you're mixing Swing with AWT code, something that should not be done unnecessarily. Stick with just Swing code, or move over to JavaFX.

Comment: Okay thanks do you know of another good api, that has similar syntax?

Comment: You still haven't told us anything about your error. What error?

Comment: In response to Hovercraft 1) It does not work meaning ta is not displayed at north (top), tb is not displayed in the center, and bb in not at south(bottom) 2) I was never taught how to space/format my code do you have any good links?

Comment: I really recommend just using GridBagLayout. Not as simple, but has always worked for me. Here is a link to help you with that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html Also, unless you're golfing, please use better variable names. Makes code easier to read.

Comment: @DJRIFFLE `p` is using a `FlowLayout`, not a `BorderLayout`...

Comment: You're also mixing Swing and AWT components, this will lead you down a painfully slippery slope of incompatiability as the components fight with each other over who should be painted on top...

Answer (score 2):

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p = new Panel();

p.add(ta,BorderLayout.NORTH);
p.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
p.add(bb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Calling `setLayout` on a different container won't change the layout manager for other containers, that would be annoying.

`Panel` is using a `FlowLayout` by default.  Instead, try using `p = new Panel(new BorderLayout())`

I'd also encourage the use of `add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);` over `add("Center", p);`, there's less that could go wrong (misspelling `center` for example)

Try and avoid mixing AWT and Swing components, they don't play well together, instead, pick a API and stick with it.  As a general recommendation, we would suggest at least Swing if not JavaFX, as they have better community support then AWT does.

Have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details